# How to get the value of "this" keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to get the value of "this" keyword inside a function in JavaScript? Or how to tell which object invoke a function or method when the invoking object is reference to "this" keyword?

```
var newObject = {name : "John", newFunction : function () { alert(this)}}
newObject.newFunction() .// output --> [object Object]
```

I was expecting the output to be `[object newObject];`

Comment: `[object Object]` is just the browser automatically calling `.toString()` on `this`, it won't tell you what variable it is assigned to. You can try using `console.log(this)` or `console.dir(this)` and checking your browser's Developer Tools to see the properties on `this`.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Not everyone uses Chrome yet ..

Comment: @user2864740 Works in Firefox and Safari too. Also could set a breakpoint and use the debugger. Lots of options. :)

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the value of `this` using console.log

```
var newObject = {name : "John", newFunction : function() { console.log(this); }}

newObject.newFunction();
```

Comment: `console.dir()` would be more appropriate in this case since `this` is an object.

Comment: does not answer my question on how to get the value of this

Answer (score 0):

You will get [object object] no matter which what variable name you give. If you want to see the object properties, you could use.

```
 var newObject = {
     name: "John",
     newFunction: function () {
         alert(JSON.stringify(this))
     }
 };
 newObject.newFunction();
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question, which is how do you get the value of this, not the properties...

Comment: Yea so thats what I stated in my first statement that you won't get "newObject" but you will get [object object] no matter which what variable name you give

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the value of `this` is by using `console.dir()`.

Just change your code to:

```
var newObject = {name : "John", newFunction : function () { console.dir(this)}};
newObject.newFunction();
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/hy4xjpLs/1)

Comment: Your answer gave the value of this --> name : Jone, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. To know how to open console in your browser to view the object, see this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

The assumption about `alert(obj)` and the [ToString] of the object (via `this`) is incorrect, and is explored below.

```
var newObject = {
    newFunction : function () { return this; }
}
var obj = newObject.newFunction();
// Trivially, `this` is returned from the function showing that it is
// the same object as the reciever the property was resolved from.
console.log("same object? " + (obj === newObject))

// And this results in [object Object], which is the same as "" + newObject
// since newObject === obj, as previously explored.
// (The name of the function/context does not matter here, as `toString()`
//  is not magically changed; "[object Object]" is the output for [ToString]
//  of an arbitrary object.)
var str = "" + obj  // -> "[object Object]"
console.log(str)    

// Leading to the predictable and see output of [object Object]
// in all three of the alert calls below.
alert(obj)          // which is is the same the following ..
alert(str)          // or with substitution ..
alert("" + obj)

// And depending upon browser and version, explore the "real" object:
console.dir(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

So, tldr: *stop* using `alert` for debugging. Use [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) (or [`console.log`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object) in some browsers), in which case the argument is *not* automatically converted to a string; alternatively, attach a breakpoint and inspect the call-frame, including `this`, live.